# Props value being altered as well

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I have a dialog component that has a `student_list` props and this dialog is being triggered by a watcher, So basically, in my main component when I increment variable `dialog_watcher++`, the dialog opens.

The `student_list` props contains data which looks like this:

```
student_list = [
   {id: 1, name: 'John'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Jane'},
   {id: 3, name: 'Jake'},
   {id: 4, name: 'Finn'},
]
```

Now in the Dialog component, In my `watch:{}` hook, I have a variable `student_list_data` where I assigned the value of the `student_list` props..

```
watch: {
    let temp = this.student_list;
    this.student_list_data = temp;
}
```

Now, in the Dialog component, I have a button where I splice some object in the `student_list_data` array.

```
_selectStudent(item) {
    //remove the selected student from the array
    const index = this.student_list_data.findIndex(obj => obj.id == item.id);
    this.student_list_data.splice(index, 1);

    //append the selected student to a new array
    this.selected_student.push(item);
}
```

Now, when I inspect in my vue devtools, I noticed that not only the `student_list_data` are being spliced, but also the `student_list` props. I checked everywhere but I dont have any function that splices data to `student_list` props.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the non-primitive variables are assigned using "=", the reference will also be copied. This may lead to the mutation for all the variables that a particular object is assigned to.

Try the following.

1. You can use JSON.stringify to convert it to string and then parse into JSON.parse.

   ```
    this.student_list_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.student_list));
   ```
2. You can use spread operator.

   ```
   this.student_list_data = [...this.student_list_data]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are cloning the `student_list` wrongly. Try with this.

```
watch: {
    this.student_list_data = [... this.student_list];
}
```